# Button reloads when inside a form Angular2 (kind of css too)

Tags: html, css, angular

I just realized that when a button is inside a form - not initialized on a FormGroup - and does nothing to do with the form, like back or cancel, it reloads the whole page.

> For the example it's gonna be a send button and a back button.

What I want to do is having two buttons at the same margin-top and with a margin between them. So if both buttons are inside the form everything goes awesome, leaving out the problem I just mentioned. If I let out the form the cancel button my style goes to hell but the flow works like Angular2 does: awesome.

Button inside form:
[image]

Button outside the form:
[image]

Well, I think that leaving the button inside the form is kind of bad practice, but I really don't know how to handle it. So, is there any way of adding a button inside the form without being part of it? (I would really expect for this Angular2 answer) Or, is it possible to do some magic inside the `.css` file in order to fake the being of the button inside the form? (I think this would be the hard way, but maybe the correct one).

Thanks a lot.

Just in case anyone asks for the code:

html (the button is gonna be inside the form):

```
<form [formGroup]="f" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()">
  <div class = "form-group">
    <input placeholder = "e-mail" formControlName = "email" type = "text">
  </div>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <input placeholder = "Password" formControlName = "password" type = "password">
  </div>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <input placeholder = "Pass-conf" formControlName = "pass-conf" type = "password">
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class = "ok" type = "submit"><img src="./assets/img1.png" alt="Ok"></button>
    <button class = "back" (click) = "back ()"><img src="./assets/img2.png" alt="Back"></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just realised what was the problem:

When a button is set inside a form, the default type of it is `submit`, so I just set the type `button` and the problem is gone.

```
<button class="back" (click)="back()" type="button"><img ...</button>
```

I'm posting this anyways just in case. Happy programming to everybody!